# Reducing the error of my derivative function

Tags: c++, derivative, pde

I would like to solve a formula
[image]
which describes a complex function E extending in r-direction (as a cylindrical coordinate system) and propagating in z-direction. Due to the impossibility to rewrite it to a time derivative I wanted to solve it as
[image]
by using the following code:

```
// MWE_derivation.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdafx.h"
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES
#include <cmath>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <complex>
#include <fstream>

//Some typedefs
typedef std::complex<double> COMPLEX;
typedef std::vector<COMPLEX> C_VECTOR;
typedef std::vector<C_VECTOR> C_MATRIX;

//Some constants
#define L0 1.2e-6
#define C90 299792458
#define K0 (2 * M_PI / L0)
#define W0 (2 * M_PI*C90 / L0)
#define FWHM0 250e-15
#define W_PULSE 3.25e-6
#define E_VAL 1.60217662e-19
#define ME 9.10938356e-31
#define M0 0.15*ME
//const double rho0 = 0;
#define BETA0 2e-11
#define HBAR 1.0545718e-34
#define N0 3.52
#define N2 4.5e-18
#define ENERGY 2.5e-6
#define POWER 1e7
#define RANGE_TIME 3
#define RANGE_SPACE 3

//Printing function
void print_vector(const C_VECTOR &data, std::string filename)
{
    std::ofstream file_out;
    file_out.open(filename);
    for (unsigned int j = 0; j < data.size(); j++)
        file_out << data[j] << ' ';
    file_out << '\n';
    file_out.close();
}

//Derivative functions

COMPLEX forward_diff_first(const C_VECTOR &x, const int p0, const double dx)
{
    return (x[p0 + 1] - x[p0]) / dx;
}

COMPLEX forward_diff_second(const C_VECTOR &x, const int p0, const double dx)
{
    return (x[p0 + 2] - x[p0 + 1] - x[p0 + 1] + x[p0]) / (dx*dx);
}

COMPLEX backward_diff_first(const C_VECTOR &x, const int p0, const double dx)
{
    return (x[p0] - x[p0 - 1]) / dx;
}

COMPLEX backward_diff_second(const C_VECTOR &x, const int p0, const double dx)
{
    return (x[p0 - 2] - x[p0 - 1] - x[p0 - 1] + x[p0]) / (dx*dx);
}

COMPLEX central_diff_first(const C_VECTOR &x, const int p0, const double dx)
{
    return (x[p0 + 1] - x[p0 - 1]) / (2 * dx);
}

COMPLEX central_diff_second(const C_VECTOR &x, const int p0, const double dx)
{
    return (x[p0 + 2] - x[p0] - x[p0] + x[p0 - 2]) / (4 * dx*dx);
}

C_VECTOR central_diff_f(const C_VECTOR &x, const double dx)
{
    C_VECTOR cdf = C_VECTOR(x.size());
    cdf[0] = forward_diff_first(x, 0, dx);
    cdf[x.size() - 1] = backward_diff_first(x, x.size() - 1, dx);
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < x.size() - 1; i++)
        cdf[i] = central_diff_first(x, i, dx);
    return cdf;
}

C_VECTOR forward_diff_f(const C_VECTOR &x, const double dx)
{
    C_VECTOR cdf = C_VECTOR(x.size());
    cdf[x.size() - 1] = backward_diff_first(x, x.size() - 1, dx);
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < x.size() - 1; i++)
        cdf[i] = forward_diff_first(x, i, dx);
    return cdf;
}

C_VECTOR backward_diff_f(const C_VECTOR &x, const double dx)
{
    C_VECTOR cdf = C_VECTOR(x.size());
    cdf[0] = forward_diff_first(x, 0, dx);
    for (unsigned int i = 1; i < x.size(); i++)
        cdf[i] = backward_diff_first(x, i, dx);
    return cdf;
}

C_VECTOR central_diff_s(const C_VECTOR &x, const double dx)
{
    C_VECTOR cdf = C_VECTOR(x.size());
    cdf[x.size() - 1] = backward_diff_second(x, x.size() - 1, dx);
    cdf[x.size() - 2] = backward_diff_second(x, x.size() - 2, dx);
    cdf[0] = forward_diff_second(x, 0, dx);
    cdf[1] = forward_diff_second(x, 1, dx);
    for (unsigned int i = 2; i < x.size() - 2; i++)
        cdf[i] = central_diff_second(x, i, dx);
    return cdf;
}

//Auxiliary functions
bool isnan(const COMPLEX &in)
{
    return isnan(in.real()) || isnan(in.imag());
}
template<typename T>
std::vector<T> linspace(T start_in, T end_in, int num_in)
{
    double start = static_cast<double>(start_in);
    double end = static_cast<double>(end_in);
    double num = static_cast<double>(num_in);
    double delta = (end - start) / (num - 1);
    std::cout << "Temp_data created\n";
    std::vector<T> linspaced(num - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < num - 1; ++i)
    {
        linspaced[i] = start + delta * i;
    }
    std::cout << "Filled linspaced\n";
    linspaced.push_back(end);
    std::cout << "linspaced filled finally\n";
    return linspaced;
}

C_VECTOR gaussian(const double w, const std::vector<double> r, const double P0)
{
    C_VECTOR ret_val(r.size());
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < r.size(); i++)
    {
        ret_val[i] = P0 * exp(-COMPLEX(2, 0) * r[i] * r[i] / (w*w));
    }
    return ret_val;
}

double get_abs(COMPLEX number)
{
    return number.real()*number.real() + number.imag()*number.imag();
}

//Main function

C_VECTOR deriv_func(const C_VECTOR &in, const double dx)
{
    return central_diff_f(in, dx);
}

C_VECTOR calc_steps(const C_VECTOR &in, const std::vector<double> r, const double dz, const int steps, const COMPLEX pref)
{
    C_VECTOR calc_val = in;
    C_VECTOR add_vec(in.size());
    C_VECTOR rho_vals(in.size());
    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < in.size(); i++)
        rho_vals[i] = 1e20;
    for (int i = 0; i < steps; i++)
    {
        print_vector(calc_val, "new_vec_" + std::to_string(i) + ".txt");
        C_VECTOR deriv = deriv_func(calc_val, abs(r[0] - r[1]));
        C_VECTOR deriv2 = central_diff_s(calc_val, abs(r[0] - r[1]));
        for (unsigned int j = 1; j < in.size(); j++)
        {
            if (isnan(deriv[j]))
            {
                std::cout << "isnan value in round " << i << " detected.\n ";
                return calc_val;
            }
        }

        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < in.size(); j++)
        {
            double r_val = r[j] + 1e-9;
            add_vec[j] = pref * dz*(deriv[j] / r_val + deriv2[j])* calc_val[j] + COMPLEX(0, 1)*(K0)*N2 / N0*get_abs(calc_val[j])*calc_val[j] - BETA0 / 2 * calc_val[j] * get_abs(calc_val[j]) - 2*M_PI*COMPLEX(0, 1)*K0*E_VAL*E_VAL/(N0*N0*M0*W0*W0)*rho_vals[j]*calc_val[j];
            calc_val[j] += add_vec[j];
        }
        //calc_val[0] = pref * dz * (deriv[1] / r[1] + deriv2[0])*calc_val[0];


    }
    return calc_val;
}

int main()
{
    double w = 3.25e-6;
    int num_vals = 1000;
    std::vector<double> r_val = linspace<double>(0.0, 3 * w, num_vals);
    C_VECTOR gauss = gaussian(w, r_val, 1e-2);
    print_vector(gauss, "gauss.txt");
    std::cout << "pref is " << COMPLEX(0, 1 / (2 * K0)) << '\n';
    C_VECTOR new_vec = calc_steps(gauss, r_val, 1e-7, 1000, COMPLEX(0, 1)/(2*K0));
    print_vector(new_vec, "new_vec.txt");
    return 0;
}
```

Unfortunately I have the problem that my derivative functions add artifacts to the function, resulting in overshooting and extremely large numbers at the borders. This can be seen in the code above with the current values, and already in iteration 2 (in the file new_vec_2.txt, at the left border). The resulting function is not smooth anymore. Adding more points only delays that problem, but does not fix it. Is there anything I can do to improve the code, and to prevent the overshooting? Or is the algorithm in fault, and I have to develop another one?

Comment: Reasons for close/downvote are welcome in the comments. Is the question too narrow?

Comment: It might be better off on [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) or either [MathOverflow](http://mathoverflow.net/) or [Mathematics Stack Exchange](http://math.stackexchange.com/).  It looks like interesting but fairly abstract.